# How can I upload / host a Reactjs website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, hosting

I'm creating a React web application project with `create-react-app`. Now it's almost ready. I did a little research on how to get a hostname and all. I found that https://www.netlify.com/ from this website I would be able to host my app.

Can anyone suggest which file(s) I required to provide them? Like main index.js or what? Or I need to upload my whole project folder? And what are the steps for it! Like FTP configuration and all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not creating anything too complex (like SSR for instance), you can simply build your react app (using something like webpack) into a bundled javascript file, create a html file that include that script, and add your css. Put those files to a server that can serve them as static assets. Boom, you're done.

But if you are looking to do more stuffs such as having the server do the build operation and then serve the files, you need a server that support nodejs, such as heroku.

EDIT: 
Since you are using create-react-app, and you can simply do `yarn build`, and `create-react-app` will build all your files to a folder named `/build`. You should see some file such as `manifest.json`, `index.html` in it.

Now, all you need is to upload those files to a web server. Any web server that has the capabilities to serve static files will do. Apache web server, expressjs, django, anything.

Comment: I have used firebase for backend and no other complex thing can I go with heroku?

Comment: What does your project looks like? Is it only the frontend? Does it includes some kind of web server to serve the static files as well (like express)?

Comment: No for web server I used firebase.

Comment: Hmm, can you explain how do you access your react app at your local machine (when you are developing)?

Comment: Using local host

Comment: Mm yeah, not exactly the answer I was looking for, haha. Can you tell me what is the url in your browser address bar when you are running the web app?

Comment: Using local host

Comment: Ah, I see, you are letting `create-react-app` to handle your local development server. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Ok can I use these files with heroku?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!